# how to recover lost AWS .pem file and putty key, which are lost due to any virus

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty, ppm

Yesterday I downloaded Filezilla, after the downloading, I got warn message from my computer,  and when I checked the download folder, all data were deleted including putty key and .PPM file. could anyone explain me please,  how can I recover these files?

Comment: Once you lose this key file there is no way to recover it. Always keep backup of .pem file in cloud.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Once you download an AWS pem you can never redownload it again (this is for security purposes if your account was compromised).

Best practice would be store anything of value in an external storage, rather than on a single users machine.

Unfortunately as it stands the instances will not be connectable over SSH without having a PEM. This isn't to say you have lost access to these instances however.

If the individual host is not of importance or can be recreated very easily, you could simply create a new SSH key within AWS and launch new instances using this configuration. You can always create an AMI of the current instances to launch ew one that is identical but specify your new SSH key when you launch.

If the hosts are important AWS support to allow you access the host via a terminal. Before accessing generate a new private/public key and then add the public key to the hosts `.ssh/authorized_keys` file once you have gained access.

The simplest solution would be to use [Sessions Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to allow you to access the host either via the console or the CLI.

For sessions manager the instances IAM role will need to grant permissions as well as the agent being previously installed.